# How to replace the \u00e2\u0080\u0099 this string into ' in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I got a value from server and i stored it in NSString object. In that string "'" is replaced with \u00e2\u0080\u0099. I tried to replace this by using replaceOccurencesOfString. But it shows an error. Herewith i displayed my code and error.

```
 [mutstr_Description replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00e2\u0080\u0099" withString:@"'" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutstr_Description length])];
```

[image]

Help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string actually has the literal characters `\`, `u`, `0`, etc., you need to do this:

```
[mutstr_Description replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099" withString:@"'" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutstr_Description length])];
```

You need to escape the backslashes.

Update - perhaps your string actually has those control characters. Try this:

```
NSString *controlChars = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C%C%C", 0xe2, 0x80, 0x99];
[mutstr_Description replaceOccurrencesOfString:controlChars withString:@"'" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutstr_Description length])];
```

Comment: I tried What you said. now error is not showing. but content is not replaced. [mutstr_Description replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u002\\u0080\\u0099" withString:@"'" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutstr_Description length])];