# Can not decode \\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099 to ’ in iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, encoding, decoding

Exact text written on admin panel is Test’s, and our PHP server is using utf8_encode() method to encode this text, which results in response on mobile end like :: 
Test\u00e2\u0080\u0099s

How could I decode it back to ’ to display on mobile app ? 
I have tried so many solutions given including utf8 decoding, but it's not working, please help.

I also tried solution given in [How to replace the \u00e2\u0080\u0099 this string into ' in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191311/how-to-replace-the-u00e2-u0080-u0099-this-string-into-in-ios), but this solution is for only a specific character, and I am looking for some generalize solution, replacement of \u00e2\u0080\u0099 with ’ seems to be a temporary solution as it don't assure if I get some other unicode in response.

Comment: I would be easier to deduce what's wrong if you'd show what you tried exactly.

Comment: Why do you write `\\` in your admin console and not just `\`? Ideally, the admin console should already recognize the character and then send it to your clients properly encoded, not just escaped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace the \u00e2\u0080\u0099 this string into ' in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191311/how-to-replace-the-u00e2-u0080-u0099-this-string-into-in-ios)

Comment: hi  DonMag, in this link solution given is for only specific character, but I am looking for any generalize solution.

Comment: Hi @Sulthan, I confirmed with server guy he is doing utf8 encoding of this text while sending it back to mobile in a JSON resposne, they are not probably escaping it.

Comment: @Richa - there seems to be many instances of almost the exact same question. Reviewing a few of them, they all indicate that the sequence `\u00e2\u0080\u0099` you are getting evaluates to `â` ... ***not*** to `’`. Are you sure this isn't a problem with the encoding on your server?

Comment: @DonMag, yes you are right, encoding from server end was not appropriate :( they were probably doing double encoding, now I am getting \u2019 for ’, and its properly displayed now after decoding.

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP...

The problem was with the server encoding, and ***not*** on the decoding end.

I'm adding this as an answer so other folks don't have to dig through the comments.